# How to select data from SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linq, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure as below

```
AS
BEGIN
    IF(@statement = 1)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [employee].[dbo].[emp_detail] ([fname], [lname], [age],[gender],
                                                   [department], [salary])
        VALUES (@fname, @lname, @age, @gender,
                @department, @salary)
    END

    IF(@statement = 2)
    BEGIN
        SELECT * 
        FROM emp_detail
    END
```

I want to select data from the table by using this stored procedure.

My code is as below :

```
List<Nullable<int>> tbl = context.USP_MVC(2,fname, lname,Convert.ToInt32(age), gender, department, salary).ToList();
```

It is showing an error

> int does not contain definition of to list

Comment: `int tbl = context.USP_MVC(2,fname, lname,Convert.ToInt32(age), gender, department, salary);`

Comment: What is the return type of USP_MVC?  I'm guessing int?

Comment: return in JSON format

Comment: Having a stored procedure that returns data in one case, but not in another (depending on a parameter) is a horribly bad design idea. I'd recommend to have **one** stored procedure that is designed to **INSERT** data, and a totally separate one that is designed to **SELECT** data - think **Single Responsibility Principle** - do one thing, but do that one thing well.

Answer (score 0):

Create a complex type of stored procedure using `.edmx` file, and change the your like this:

```
List<StoredProcedureName_Result> tbl = context.USP_MVC(2, fname, lname, Convert.ToInt32(age), gender, department, salary).ToList();
```